# Deleting text in a plot

Tags: r, plot, plotrix

I'm using the plotting function `sizetree` from `library(plotrix)` (Version: `3.8-1`). This function has a `showcount` argument that allows some counts in parenthesis to show on the plot (see pic below).

But I wonder why when I use `showcount=FALSE`, the counts and parentheses around them don't go away? Is there any way to make them disappear?

```
h = "
sssss ooooooo ggggg tttt
a     1       1     0
a     2       1     1
b     1       1     0
b     1       2     0
c     2       1     0
c     3       2     1
d     1       1     0
d     1       1     0
e     1       1     0"
h = read.table(text=h,h=T)

library(plotrix)
plotrix::sizetree(h,showcount = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: For what it's worth it looks like this may have been fixed in version 3.8.2 of plotrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function seems to to have a bug in it. The function call itself recursively to add each of the columns, but the function neglects to pass along the `showcount` value to each of the subsequent calls. Here's one way to "patch" the function. Essentally we are making a copy and changing a line of code. This method is really fragile and may easily break with other versions of the package, but this was tested with `plotrix_3.7-8`.

```
sizetree <- plotrix::sizetree
environment(sizetree) <- globalenv()
# This "path" navigates the AST for the function to find the offending line of code
path <- c(8, 3, 5, 4, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 8, 3, 5)
orig <- body(sizetree)[[path]]
orig
## Problem line, no showcount= parameter
# sizetree(nextx, right, top, right + 1, lastcenter = top - xfreq[bar]/2, 
#     showval = showval, stacklabels = stacklabels, firstcall = FALSE, 
#     col = newcol, border = border, base.cex = base.cex)
## fix it up
scall <- orig
scall$showcount <- quote(showcount)
body(sizetree)[[path]] <- scall
```

Then we can run

```
sizetree(h,showcount = FALSE)
```

to get
[image: sizetree without counts]

Comment: I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70726042/16762740) is exactly in line with your above answer. May I kindly ask if you could consider taking a look?