# Modify three lines of code in a function from an R package

Tags: r, function, package

function `Effect.lm()` from R package `effects` has a bug that can be resolved by adding 3 lines of code.

I have the solution below, but is there a way to implement this change to `Effect.lm()` from R package `effects`?

I intend to use `Effect.lm()` indirectly (via another function), and the change must be replicable by other users.

ps. I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68570496/16762740) may be relevant.
Unfortunately, @Ben Bolker 's answer (his R code), as he mentions, doesn't achieve my goal above.

```
library(effects)

# Delete line 164 in the following
View(effects::Effect.lm)

# Then, in its place, add the following 3 lines

  use <- !is.na(mod$coefficients)     # new
  mmat <- mod.matrix[, use]           # new
  if (any(is.na(V))) V <- V[use, use] # new
```

Comment: Did you contact the maintainer/file an issue? Did my answer solve your problem? (If so you are encouraged to accept it; if not, you're welcome to comment/explain why it didn't work)

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to do this is to download the package source, edit the source appropriately, then run `R CMD INSTALL` to install the modified package.

If your workflow only needs to call `Effect.lm` directly (i.e. not indirectly through other package functions), then you can use `dump()` to dump the function definition to a file, edit the file, then `source()` it.

There are tricks involving turning the body of the function into a character vector, editing it, and replacing it, something like

```r
oldfun <- effects:::Effect.lm
## this is the 165th line of the *body*
replace_line <- 165
s <- deparse(body(oldfun))
new_lines <- c("use <- !is.na(mod$coefficients)",
               "mmat <- mod.matrix[, use]",
               "if (any(is.na(V))) { V <- V[use, use] } ")
s <- c(s[1:(replace_line-1)], new_lines, s[(replace_line+1):length(s)])
newfun <- oldfun
body(newfun) <- parse(text=s)
```

but this is clever and fragile and **will not work** if you're trying to replace the function within a package environment (or, it may work, but only after a lot of messing around with trying to unlock environments etc.).

Or you could e-mail the maintainer and ask them to fix the bug ...